# Combination of SSH key auth, and two-factor authentication

Tags: ssh, password, pam, two-factor

I was wondering if it is possible to accomplish the following, all at the same time:

- Disable root logins
- Enable SSH login for personal user, **only** via SSH keys
- Enable SSH login for unprivileged user, **with** password authentication **and** two-factor authentication only

Using the `Match` block in `sshd_config` I was able to set this up so that in general `PasswordAuthentication` was disabled except for the unprivileged user (lets call it `peon`).  SSH keys were required for logging in to the personal user (who has sudo capabilities).

However, when I try to enable two-factor authentication (`pam_google_authenticator`) I have to turn on `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` which seems to **not** work in a `Match` block, and is therefore turning password authentication back on for everyone.

Is there a way to accomplish this?  I'm not overly great with this type of stuff, so detailed explanations would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Recent versions of `openssh` include the `AuthenticationMethods` option:

Debian backported `openssh-6.2` [a while back](http://list-archives.org/2013/10/25/debian-backports-lists-debian-org/pushed-openssh-to-wheezy-backports/f/7452999512), so I expect this to be available in Raspbian as well.

> Specifies the authentication methods that must be successfully completed for a user to be granted access.

You can have the main block of your `sshd_config` with `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` enabled:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin no
```

and then use `AuthenticationMethods` in your `Match` blocks (use `Group` matching instead of `User` matching to ease scalabity):

```
Match Group personal
  AuthenticationMethods publickey

Match Group peon
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

Aditionally, you can use [`pam_succeed_if(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_succeed_if) to trigger the two-factor-authentication only if a matching group requires it:

```
 auth required pam_succeed_if.so quiet user ingroup peon
```

Comment: While I know use of `User` isn't the focus of your answer, I'd still recommend changing the example to using `Group` instead of `User`. Embedding usernames in a config file tends not to scale well.

Comment: It's just for a Raspberry pi at the moment :)

Comment: `Bad configuration option: AuthenticationMethods` -- `Directive 'AuthenticationMethods' is not allowed within a Match block`  Does this mean I need to update ssh?

Comment: Match block needs to be at the end of the sshd_config, because it applies to all lines after it.