# Require both LDAP authentication *and* ssh auth

Tags: ssh, openldap

I would like to enable the following:
Linux ec2 instances in AWS that perform LDAP authentication of users who have no home directory currently on the box.  I have a working openLDAP in AWS for the task

Once LDAP authenticated:

- The user's home directory will get created
- The user's public ssh key is retrieved from their `sshPublicKey` attribute in LDAP and they can only log on if their local sshPrivateKey matches

I know how to do LDAP auth **OR** retrieval of public key via an `ldapsearch` but I want to do both.

The scenario I am trying to mitigate against is when an employee leaves the company: I can just disable their account in openLDAP and even if their public key exists on machines, they won't be able to use them because they will also fail ldap auth.

I've hunted round on StackExchanges and don't think I've found what I'm looking for. The closest I've come is

[SSH key authentication using LDAP](https://serverfault.com/questions/653792/ssh-key-authentication-using-ldap)

[Combination of SSH key auth, and two-factor authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/579341/combination-of-ssh-key-auth-and-two-factor-authentication)

Comment: What do you use to LDAPize your linux box? nslcd (nss-pam-ldapd), nss-pam-ldap or something else? You can easily disable user by changing `loginShell` to `/bin/false` or `/usr/sbin/nologin` in LDAP if you're reading this attribute.

Comment: Thanks @JakubJindra. I wanted to use ssh as well as ldapAuth to act as an additional factor of authentication so requiring ssh key as well as user/pass. Would disabling the user as you described apply in this scenario too?
My proof of concept with ldap auth only was nss-pam-ldap

Comment: If the user exists only in LDAP database and not in file database `/etc/passwd`, it will be the same.
He would be able to authenticate, but then his loginShell won't let him in.
Better approach is use one LDAP attribute to differentiate enabled and disabled users. And filter by this attribute. The user will simply disappear from the system.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not clear how I go about setting up both LDAP auth *and* the retrieval of the user's ssh public key . Sorry if I'm not asking the question in the right way. Basically is both authentication using LDAP user/pass and also ssh pub/priv key able to be applied together, if so how?

Comment: OK, I'll try to sumarize it in the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Authentication**

There's `AuthorizedKeysCommand` and `AuthorizedKeysCommandUser` in [sshd_config(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) since OpenSSH 6.2. You need that to authenticate user against his/her `sshPublicKey` which is stored in LDAP. You don't even need ldapsearch to get the sshPublicKey - curl can do it too, since it's knows the ldap protocol.

When `AuthorizedKeysCommand` is defined but the command won't return any public key, openssh server continues with `AuthorizedKeysFile` and then with `PasswordAuthentication`.

On AWS EC2 the PasswordAuthentication is disabled so If You really want it, You need to enable it in config. But I wouldn't recommend PasswordAuthentication at all today.

Small recap: you want these options in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
`AuthorizedKeysFile`, `AuthorizedKeysCommand`, `AuthorizedKeysCommandUser` and `PasswordAuthentication`.

**Disabling user**

As mentioned in discussion under the question: You can either use `loginShell` ldap attribute and modify it's value to `/bin/false` or `/usr/sbin/nologin` or use another attribute and add it into search query. This differs depending on Your setup.

What's Your setup? [nslcd (nss-pam-ldapd)](https://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/), [nss-pam-ldap](https://www.padl.com/OSS/pam_ldap.html), [sssd](https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd) or something else?

Comment: Thanks Jakub, but this still seems only to do ssh auth of the user. Not validating their user/password against ldap, followed by ssh auth on the retrieved key. Maybe what I'm considering just isn't possible

Comment: So You want to authenticate by pubkey from ldap even after that using using ldap password? I think It's possible using pam configuration. But editing pam can be dangerous.

Comment: Yes, as it says in the title
`Require both LDAP authentication *and* ssh auth`
Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: OK, then try following solution: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/130116/202480